# How to get home page ID?

Tags: plugins, homepage, id

I'm building a Wordpress plugin in which I need to get the **HOME page ID value**.

Do you know how can I get it?

I know that we can get the current ID with `the_ID()` or `get_the_ID()` function, but I need specificly the **HOME page ID value**.

My plugin is located at the following directory path:

```
wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/
```

Comment: Are you using front-page.php or you created a specific page just to be the home page of your website? If you used front-page.php (or index.php), then you don't have any ID associated with it.

Comment: The homepage do not have an ID

Comment: Can you elaborate on your roadblock requiring the homepage ID?  I can't seem to imagine a scenario where using `is_front_page()` and writing a slightly longer function wouldn't solve every problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`$pageID = get_option('page_on_front');` should get you the Page ID of the page set as 'Front Page' (Homepage) in WordPress options.

`$pageID = get_option('page_for_posts');` should get you the Page ID of the page set as 'Posts Page' in WordPress options.

In any case, if the returned value is `0`, that means no static page is set for that option.

Comment: Home page is the posts page - this is the option for the Front page, which might colloquially be known as the home page, but in WordPress means something different.

Answer (score 7):

If by Home Page you mean the page designated as the Posts page, the ID is stored in the option `page_for_posts`. If the value is 0, there is no designated home page.