# When using global $post in blog index file (home.php) it returns the latest blog post instead of current page

Tags: blog-page

In my `home.php` file I have only this code:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    print_r($post->ID);
    die();
?>
```

This is printing the ID of the latest blog post, but what I want is to get the ID of the current page (the page I set as the Posts Page in Settings). It seems that I am already in "The Loop". How can I get the global `$post` object for the current page rather than the first post in the loop?

Comment: ["how to get home page ID'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203099/how-to-get-home-page-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿How about getting the ID from de configuration?

```
<?php $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); ?>
```

As the page you are looking for now displays the posts, you are in the loop for posts, not the loop for the page.

Comment: I guess that will work. It seems like there should be another way, but maybe not.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered `get_queried_object_id()` which gets the current page's ID even when you're in the loop. That's what I was looking for. Your answer is technically correct also, so I'll leave it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I accepted is technically correct, but I wanted to follow up with another answer that is what I originally was looking for. The function `get_queried_object_id()` will get the page's ID even when you're within the loop.